# jquery marking values less than selected value as checked

Tags: jquery

I have numerous checkboxes that are prices and what I've tried to do is the following

When someone selects a prices/checkbox, it will automatically check the values that are less than the selected value.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppw5z/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="prices">
    <input type="checkbox" value="59.99" />59.99
    <input type="checkbox" value="69.99" />69.99
    <input type="checkbox" value="79.99" />79.99
    <input type="checkbox" value="89.99" />89.99
    <input type="checkbox" value="99.99" />99.99
    <input type="checkbox" value="124.99" />124.99
    <input type="checkbox" value="149.99" />149.99
    <input type="checkbox" value="199.99" />199.99
    <input type="checkbox" value="200.00" />200.00
</div>
​
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.prices input[type=checkbox]').live('click', function (){
     console.log(this);
     $(this).attr('checked', true);
     var chosenPrice = $(this).val();
     console.log(chosenPrice);
     $(".prices input").filter(function(){ 
     return  $(this).attr("value") <=chosenPrice}).attr('checked', true);
});​
```

It selects some values but it doesn't seem to work as it should be. check out the fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified part of your code.. You need to do only check the other checkboxes when the current checkbox is checked..
Also need to convert the string to a number using

`parseFloat()` or `Number()`

```
$('.prices input[type=checkbox]').live('click', function() {
    console.log(this);
    var $this = $(this) ;
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
        var chosenPrice = $this.val();
        console.log(chosenPrice);
        $(".prices input").filter(function() {
            return parseFloat($(this).attr("value")) <= chosenPrice
        }).prop('checked', true);
    }
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ppw5z/7/)**

Answer (score 1):

The script is comparing strings. Try modifying the value to make it a number.

```
var chosenPrice = Math.floor($(this).val());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ppw5z/2/

Comment: This won't work if you have $99.99 and $99.98.  Clicking on $99.99 won't click $99.98. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppw5z/2/)

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).val()` returns a string, not a number, so you aren't actually comparing numbers.

Convert your value into a float and it should work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.prices input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var value = parseFloat($this.val());

    $this.siblings().andSelf().prop('checked', false).filter(function() {
        return parseFloat($(this).val()) <= value;
    }).prop('checked', true);
});​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ppw5z/6/**

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the comparisons being done are done as strings instead of as floats.  You can fix this with the following code:

```
$('.prices input[type=checkbox]').live('click', function (){
     var chosenPrice = $(this).val();
     $(".prices input").filter(function(){ 
         return parseFloat($(this).val()) <= parseFloat(chosenPrice)).attr('checked', true);
});​
```

**Demo:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppw5z/1/)